# Generating Moving 2D Sinusoidal Pattern

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am trying to generate a video of a pattern as shown below which moves horizontally using OpenCV in python.

[image: 2-D sinusoidal Patter]

I have written it in the following way. The video file is generated without any errors but the file doesn't open in any video players

```
        import cv2
        import numpy as np
        from cv2 import VideoWriter, VideoWriter_fourcc

        video = VideoWriter('_sine_pattern_gen_'+str(60)+'_fps.avi', VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42'), 60, (346, 260))

        x = np.arange(346)  # generate 1-D sine wave of required period 
        y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x / 20) 

        y += max(y) # offset sine wave by the max value to go out of negative range of sine 

        frame = np.array([[y[j] for j in range(346)] for i in range(260)], dtype='uint8') # create 2-D array of sine-wave

        for _ in range(0, 346):
            video.write(frame)
            shifted_frame =  np.roll(frame, 2, axis=1) # roll the columns of the sine wave to get moving effect
            frame = shifted_frame 

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        video.release()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with using a single-channel grayscale image when `VideoWriter` is expecting a color image.  This can be fixed by using the flag `isColor=False`.

Also, since the images are type `uint8` and `y` only goes up to 2, this will look like a black video instead of the image you show.  You can scale `y` to go the full 0-255 range by multiplying `y[j]*127`.  The following should work:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv2 import VideoWriter, VideoWriter_fourcc

fname = '_sine_pattern_gen_'+str(60)+'_fps.avi'
video = VideoWriter(fname, VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42'), 60, (346, 260), isColor=False)

x = np.arange(346)  # generate 1-D sine wave of required period 
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x / 20)

y += max(y) # offset sine wave by the max value to go out of negative range of sine 

frame = np.array([[y[j]*127 for j in range(346)] for i in range(260)], dtype=np.uint8) # create 2-D array of sine-wave

for _ in range(0, 346):
    video.write(frame)
    shifted_frame =  np.roll(frame, 2, axis=1) # roll the columns of the sine wave to get moving effect
    frame = shifted_frame 

video.release()
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. In fact, it throws an error message, which wasn't happening earlier. 
`OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id 12 and format 'avi / AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)'`.
I tried looking up the error and the suggestions were to change the codec used. However, on doing that I ended up with my initial error

Comment: OK, that must not have been the issue then.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I have a question. Does the `VideoWriter` class require the images written onto it to be colour images? I saw the documentation online (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html) and didn't see that condition explicitly mentioned anywhere.

Comment: There is an `isColor` parameter that has a default of `True`. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ac3478f6257454209fa99249cc03a5c59 . This is probably a better solution to set that to `False`, so I updated the answer.